# Getting last word typed in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the last word that I type into a text area and send it into a function.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        $('#my_text').focus(function () {
            $('#my_text').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == '32') {
                    console.log("Space");
                    var lastWord = "";
                    //Code to get last word that was typed
                    getLastWord(lastWord);
                    //$('DivToScroll').css("keyword");
                }
            });
            console.log("Focused");
        });
    });
```

I can't seem to find the right code to get the last word typed in the text area, I have looked around and have had no such luck either. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `var words = $(this).text().split(' '); console.log(words[words.length-1])`

Comment: You're binding an event handler inside another = bad idea.

Comment: @TJ what do you mean exactly, like how would I fix it? I thought they all had to be inside the `$(document).ready`

Comment: @TJ In some cases, it may actually make sense (eg bind a click event inside a document ready event) But yes, in this case, the keydown event handler will trigger as many times at the input is focused (If I click in and out of the input 5 times, and press a key, the function will execute 5 times)

Comment: And there is no element of type `document` inside DOM, you should use `$(document)` From DOC: `$().ready( handler ) (this is not recommended)`

Comment: `var word = $(this).text().split(' ').pop();` why use length when there is pop()

Comment: What do you mean last word typed in? last word as in position or last word as in actually typed anywhere in the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said juvian:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my_text').on('keyup', function (e) {
        if(e.which == 32){ // Press space
            var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
            var lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
            console.log(lastWord);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does`.focusout()` do exactly?

Comment: @bbesase It triggers when the element loses focus. Kind of like `blur`, except for the fact that it supports event bubbling.

Comment: `.focusout` is call when the textarea loose the focus, so you don't call the function each time you press a key but only when you have dont to write in your textarea. It can not be what you want, else use `input` or `change` event instead of `focusout`.

Comment: The OP wants the last word that user types in the textarea not the last word in the textarea.last word may be first word or anyword inside textarea.

Comment: Yeah I need to be so that when the user hits `spacebar` then it gets the last word and sends it to the function

Comment: @Shaiful Islam i assume he doesn't mean that.

Comment: @JonathanTribouharet Yeah I want it so that it gets the last word typed once they hit `spacebar`

Comment: You want create a kind of tag system? If the user hit `spacebar` do you want to clean the textarea?

Comment: No not clean, just get the last word they typed send it to the function, then based on the word it will do stuff. But Keep everything inside the text area